# Mixing C & Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I'm using the soft-core Cortex-M0,keil uvision 5,vivado 14.4
i interfaced an adder with my arm architecture
first,i used the assembly language nd the simulation in vivado simulator worked correctly.

my first assembly code--->

```
Reset_Handler PROC
GLOBAL Reset_Handler
ENTRY
LDR R1,=0x59000000
LDR R0,=0x33
STR R0,[R1]`
```

---

Now, i want to use C and Assembly language but simulation doesn't work, it can't access to the adder registers

the second assembly-->

```
Reset_Handler PROC
GLOBAL Reset_Handler
ENTRY
IMPORT __main
LDR R0, =__main 
BX R0
ENDP
```

---

the C code-->

```
#define AAA 0x59000000
int main(void)
{
  *(unsigned int*)AAA=0x44;
}
```

Comment: am using keil uvision5 (SW: assembly&c) ,nd vivado(HW:verilog), just there is a problem with the simulation in vivado simulator

Comment: Sorry,i'm a beginner, i want to know if the __main()  called  the main() function i write or no

Answer (score 1):

my assembly code

```
; Vector Table Mapped to Address 0 at Reset
```

```
                    PRESERVE8
                    THUMB

                    AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY               
                    EXPORT  __Vectors
```

__Vectors               DCD     0x0000FFFC
                        DCD     Reset_Handler
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0
                        DCD     0

```
                    ; External Interrupts

                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0
                    DCD     0

            AREA |.text|, CODE, READONLY
```

;Reset Handler
Reset_Handler   PROC
                GLOBAL Reset_Handler
                ENTRY
                IMPORT  __main
                LDR     R0, =__main
                 BX      R0

```
            ENDP
            ALIGN       4                    
            END
```